# mysql server does not use all available RAM

Tags: mysql, performance, config

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit=10000
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
max_heap_table_size = 2GB
query_cache_limit = 256M
key_buffer_size = 6GB
innodb_table_locks = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100M
join_buffer_size = 32M
max_connections = 400
max_user_connections = 1400
#skip-bdb
key_buffer = 48M
# max_allowed_packet = 68M
max_allowed_packet = 256M
tmp_table_size = 3GB
table_cache = 800
sort_buffer_size = 1M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
server-id  = 1
wait_timeout = 28800
query_cache_size = 50M
thread_cache_size = 1024
long_query_time = 4
```

We have this config on 15GB RAM VPS server, which is used for MySQL only. The problem is that the server is using only 3GB of RAM during the heaviest traffic.

Can anyone suggest what should be adjusted in config to use all available RAM?

mysqltuner.pl says this:
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 15.0G (103% of installed RAM)

Comment: That's a mighty small innodb_buffer_pool_size, I'd up that considerably. That possible theoretical memory usage is when you have full connections: if you want to stay under or near the max memory under those conditions, I'd lower the max user connections.

Comment: What's the size of your db?